# bank error magento crud 2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create a crud to save a form in the database. Before, I normally opened the form, but I changed the Model folder and now all that appears is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `vendor_test` AS `main_table` WHERE (`id` = '')
```

my dataprovider.php

```
 <?php



namespace Vendor\Test\Model;

use Vendor\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Formulario\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $blogCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $blogCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $blog) {
            $this->loadedData[$blog->getBlogId()] = $blog->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of "id" use "blog_id" in your ui_component xml

Comment: Please add table schema information and Formulario ResourceModel